# Xcode Property Automation

Tags: objective-c, xcode

Xcode has these handy time savers in the scripts menu called "Code->Place Accessor Defs on Clipboard" and "Code->Place Accessor Decls on Clipboard". These scripts allow you to automate the generation of getter and setter methods for any highlighted instance variables.

Does anyone know of a similar script that outputs Objective-C 2.0 Property declaration statements?

Comment: I realize how to add scripts to XCode, what I'm looking for are the scripts themselves.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out:

1. [Matt Gallagher's property accessors script for XCode](http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html)
2. [Accessorizer](http://www.kevincallahan.org/software/accessorizer.html) if you want a whole application for the generation of property accessors.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Edit User Scripts..." menu option in the Scripts menu to create these yourself.

Answer (score 0):

I also recommend textexpander which makes the process a little more intuitive and generalized such that the same "snippets" can be used across text editors.